# Changing keyboard shortcuts in gedit

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

There's no way to change the shortcuts from the GUI or with a plugin, which is odd because there are ways to tweak far less important features. Every similar question about this topic is from years ago and the answers no longer work.

Is there a config file somewhere or a third-party plugin for key bindings? More specifically, I want to map the redo shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, but a general solution would be useful.

Comment: On my 16.04 `gedit` the undo is mapped to `Ctrl`+`Z`. What version are you using? Also `Ctrl`+`U` is already mapped to convert text to upper-case. `Ctrl`+`L` reverses and changes text to lower-case.

Comment: Same on 18.04: it's `Ctrl+Z`, not `Ctrl+Shift+Z`. Sadly, my money's on your not being able to switch gedit's keybinds. But let's see!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the redo shortcut. But yeah, I noticed that changing one shortcut would affect the others, which is why I'm asking for a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

The undo shortcut is actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut is for the "redo undo" feature. To see a list off all the file editing shortcuts see the [online reference](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en) or from within `gedit` press <kbd>F1</kbd> to access help screen and select `Shortcut Keys` option:

[image: gedit shortcut keys.png]

Finally I don't see a way of changing these settings but if you do you will need to ensure you find the right keys you are mapping from and ensure the keys you are mapping to aren't already assigned for a different purpose. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is already assigned to convert the highlighted text to all upper-case characters.